# How to manage array CRUD operations & input state management for a video Timeline component?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, crud

I made a video timeline component for manually adding subtitles to a video. The user inputs 6 number inputs fields for hours, minutes & seconds, then clicks on add button on right. It should then store the new timeline on 'timelines' array and render the Timeline component.

The timeline component looks something like this:

From *00*:*08*:*12*  to __:*08*:*22* (+add) (-delete)

(Add New button)

The user must add the timelines (6 inputs) manually and click on the add button to save. The 'Add New' button below is to add 'New Timeline' component. The add button on right is to add the timeline in 'timelines' state array.

I have 2 problems with the code.

1. First I'm not able to control the input states. I cant enter numbers in the input fields.
2. I'm unable to do add new timeline operation properly.

Please see code below:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';

    const VideoElement = () => {
    
       const [timelines, setTimelines] = useState([]);
       const [timeline, setTimeline] = useState({
          id: 0,
          fromHours: 0,
          fromMinutes: 8,
          fromSeconds: 10,
          toHours: 0,
          toMinutes: 8,
          toSeconds: 20,
       });
    
    const onChangeTimelineHandler = (e) => {
          setTimeline({ ...timeline, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
       };
    
       // Create new timeline
       const addTimelineHandler = () => {
          setTimelines([...timelines, { ...timeline, id: uuidv4() }]);
       };
    
       // Delete Timeline
       const deleteTimeline = (id) => {
          const newTimelines = timelines.filter((tl) => tl.id !== id);
          setTimelines(newTimelines);
       };
    
       // Adds New Timeline in the setTimeline container
       const addNewTimeline = () => {

          setTimeline({
             id: 0,
             fromHours: 0,
             fromMinutes: 0,
             fromSeconds: 0,
             toHours: 0,
             toMinutes: 0,
             toSeconds: 0,
          });

          setTimelines([...timelines, { ...timeline, id: uuidv4() }]);
       };
    
    return (
      <div className="timelines">
                            {timelines &&
                               timelines.map((tl, index) => (
                                  <Timeline
                                     index={index}
                                     key={tl.id}
                                     timeline={tl}
                                     onChangeTimelineHandler={
                                        onChangeTimelineHandler
                                     }
                                     addTimelineHandler={addTimelineHandler}
                                     deleteTimeline={deleteTimeline}
                                  />
                               ))}
                         </div>
    )
    }
```

The Timeline component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { MdDelete } from 'react-icons/md';
import { IoMdAdd } from 'react-icons/io';

const Timeline = ({
   timeline,
   onChangeTimelineHandler,
   addTimelineHandler,
   deleteTimeline,
   index,
}) => {
   const {
      id,
      fromHours,
      fromMinutes,
      fromSeconds,
      toHours,
      toMinutes,
      toSeconds,
   } = timeline;

   return (
      <div className="timeline">
         <label htmlFor="">{index + 1}.</label>

         <div className="timelineFromInputContainer">
            <input
               placeholder="00"
               type="number"
               name="fromHours"
               id="fromHours"
               value={fromHours}
               onChange={onChangeTimelineHandler}
            />
            <span className="colon">:</span>
            <input
               placeholder="00"
               type="number"
               name="fromMinutes"
               id="fromMinutes"
               value={fromMinutes}
               onChange={onChangeTimelineHandler}
            />
            <span className="colon">:</span>
            <input
               placeholder="00"
               type="number"
               name="fromSeconds"
               id="fromSeconds"
               value={fromSeconds}
               onChange={onChangeTimelineHandler}
            />
         </div>

         <span className="timelineTo">To</span>

         <div className="timelineToInputContainer">
            <input
               placeholder="00"
               type="number"
               name="toHours"
               id="toHours"
               value={toHours}
               onChange={onChangeTimelineHandler}
            />
            <span className="colon">:</span>
            <input
               placeholder="00"
               type="number"
               name="toMinutes"
               id="toMinutes"
               value={toMinutes}
               onChange={onChangeTimelineHandler}
            />
            <span className="colon">:</span>
            <input
               placeholder="00"
               type="number"
               name="toSeconds"
               id="toSeconds"
               value={toSeconds}
               onChange={onChangeTimelineHandler}
            />
         </div>

         <div className="timelineIcons">
            <IoMdAdd
               color="#fff"
               className="addTimelineIcon"
               onClick={addTimelineHandler}
            />
            <MdDelete
               className="deleteTimelineIcon"
               color="#B00015"
               onClick={() => deleteTimeline(id)}
            />
         </div>
      </div>
   );
};

export default Timeline;
```

Comment: It's okay, issue fixed when I removed 'value' attributes from input fields. Crud operations also resolved .

Comment: If you were able to resolve your question, please add an answer and accept it. In the future have a look at how to create a [Minimal, reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)